# sudo yum install httpd is throwing errors

Tags: apache, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-code-deploy, bitbucket-aws-code-deploy

I am creating CI with code deploy amazon ec2, unfortunately after git push I get the following error.

```
scripts/install_dependencies
The script at the specified location: scripts/install_dependencies run as user root failed with exit code 1 View more.

LifecycleEvent - BeforeInstall
Script - scripts/install_dependencies
[stdout]Loaded plugins: priorities, update-motd, upgrade-helper
[stdout]Resolving Dependencies
[stdout]--> Running transaction check
[stdout]---> Package httpd.x86_64 0:2.2.34-1.16.amzn1 will be installed
[stdout]--> Processing Dependency: httpd-tools = 2.2.34-1.16.amzn1 for package: httpd-2.2.34-1.16.amzn1.x86_64
[stdout]--> Processing Dependency: apr-util-ldap for package: httpd-2.2.34-1.16.amzn1.x86_64
[stdout]--> Running transaction check
[stdout]---> Package apr-util-ldap.x86_64 0:1.5.4-6.18.amzn1 will be installed
[stdout]---> Package httpd-tools.x86_64 0:2.2.34-1.16.amzn1 will be installed
[stdout]--> Processing Conflict: httpd24-tools-2.4.37-1.83.amzn1.x86_64 conflicts httpd-tools < 2.4.37
[stdout]--> Finished Dependency Resolution
[stderr]Error: httpd24-tools conflicts with httpd-tools-2.2.34-1.16.amzn1.x86_64
[stderr]Error: httpd24 conflicts with httpd-2.2.34-1.16.amzn1.x86_64
[stdout] You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
[stdout] You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Here is my scripts/install_dependencies

```
#!/bin/bash
yum install -y httpd
```

What am I doing wrong with my codes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your script looks correct but there is a conflict with an existing package. The Amazon Linux AMI already has a version of httpd installed. Try using a different AMI (maybe a custom one you create with the right versions) or have your script remove the existing version before installing a new one e.g. `sudo yum remove httpd-tools-2.2.34-1.16.amzn1.x86_64`